# Tcp and receiving order

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm preparing an exam and I stumbled upon kind of interesting question. Basically what happens when for whatever reason the receiver receives the packets in reverse order?

For example I have a window of size 2 and I send packet 2 and 3 but 3 arrives faster than 2.
I'm not quite sure about the answer so I'll ask here.

Does the receiver sends a duplicate ack upon arrival of 3 and then ack2 upon arrival of 2?

And then, what happens to the transmission window?

Comment: TCP will ACK for a window, but the sender will not send anything more until it receives an ACK for the window. The window can be large, and segments within the window can arrive out of order, but TCP will reorder the segments.

Comment: Ok,thanks, upon receiving the window ack my window will grow accordingly in this case from 2 to 4 assuming in still in slow star,right?

Comment: There is a lot that goes into deciding the window size. You should look at [RFC 793, TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt), which is the definition of TCP, and it explains how it works.

Comment: Im still confused, should It follow the standard anti congestion measures? so upon receiving 3 dups retransmit the first packet of the window(assuming it was larger) and so on?